# Special characters in dust.js key?

Tags: json, dust.js

I am trying to use a dust.js template with JSON data that has keys that contain special characters, like ":" and "#".

How can I specify these keys in my template?

For example:

```
JSON data:
{
    "opensearch:totalResults": 200,
    "#text": "some data"
}
```

dust.js template:

```
<div>There are {opensearch:totalResults} items found</div>
```

This does not resolve correctly and simply prints the template text instead of replacing with the JSON data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the Problem is that keys are not valid in dustjs.This is the pegjs rule that we are using to validate keys:

```
key "key"
 = h:[a-zA-Z_$] t:[0-9a-zA-Z_$-]*
 { return h + t.join('') }
```

This means that the key is valid only if:

- Starts with a letter, underscore or $
- The rest of the key is a letter, underscore, $ or dash (-)

As you can see the # and the : are not valid symbols to be part of the key.

If you need to add it, you can open an issue or just sent a pull request, explaining why you need this feature.